# Perform database actions in the background every 10 minutes

Tags: android, background, timer

I want to perform database actions in the background every 10 minutes. What is the best method?

Maybe:

- Threads: *how?*
- Services: *very complicated?*
- AsyncTasks: *too long period*

My current approach:

```
CountDownTimer clearDBsCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(600000, 600000) {
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        ClearDBs();
    }
};

private void ClearDBs() {
    // Clearing databases here
    clearDBsCountDownTimer.start();
}
```

But it's not working: I think because the `ClearDBs()` method waits for the `CountDownTimer` to finish, right?

But how to do that correctly: any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AlarmManager + IntentService is the cleanest approach.

With AlarmManager you can schedule periodic IntentServices.

An IntentService is a service that performs a specific action in a background thread (`onHandleIntent()` call) and dies.

They make a perfect mix to perform periodic jobs in background.

Check for example [this post](http://dhimitraq.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/using-intentservice-with-alarmmanager-to-schedule-alarms/).

Please be careful with this kind of operations since they could result in draining the battery (and having angry users).

As suggested by @Squonk you can use `setRepeating(...)` or `setInexactRepeating(...)` to schedule periodic events.

If you want to perform this background task only when your app is in foreground, you can still cancel the event calling [manager.cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: But I only want the database manipulations to be done while the app is running. And how can I run it repeatadly?

Comment: @fedepaol : "...you will have to schedule another event inside the onHandleIntent() call." This is not necessary when using the `AlarmManager` methods `setInexactRepeating(...)` or `setRepeating(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a [bound service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder) would be a good idea.

And for threading use [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Comment: Given that he wants to perform background job only when the app is active this is a better approach, since bounding will result in automatic starting / stopping of the service. The only thing he must care of is to stop the thread when the service gets unbound. +1 for your reply

Comment: I completely agree with you and that's the reason i did not propose `TimerTask` which `scheduleAtFixed` is kind of unstable specially when you try to stop, at least that's what i have found couple of time when i worked with that. On the other side `ExecutorService` provide lot of options to check and stop a running thread. He just need to hook into with stop functionality.

Comment: However I did not know about that since his comment :-). IntentService + AlarmManager feels more solid but I must admit it could be trickier to start / stop than a bounded service.

Comment: @minhaz But thank you for your ideas, I may use ist somewhere else.